# Pickle/unpickle a file without needing the filedependices

Tags: python, deserialization, pickle

Say I have two files `main.py` and `Utils.py` with

```py
# Utils.py

class Helper:
    def fit(self,X,y):
        pass
    def predict(self,X):
        pass
```

and

```py
# main.py
from Utils import Helper
helper = Helper()
helper.fit(2,3)

with open("./helper.pkl","wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(helper,f)
```

If I then push ´"helper.pkl"´ to e.g S3 storage and then have a production server which pulls it, and I try to unpickle it, I get the  `"No module name Utils"`.

In this example it's fairly easy to just also push `Utils.py` but isn't there a way where we can just pickle/save an object and use the object "as is" without having to include the dependices used for creation?

Comment: That could be - I don't know to be honest. There might some, obvious, serialization/deserialization knowledge I don't know of. But if that is indeed the case, is there a way to save objects?

Comment: Oh also: why not just upload the python file to the server so the module and class exist?

Comment: If pickle included the class definitions, it would be impossible to ever add features or fix bugs in those classes.